# Magento is sending the transaction as auth_only

Tags: magento-1.8, payment, authorize.net

how do i get magento and authorize direct post method to authorize and capture??
I have it in "Payment Action" selected as "authorize and capture” and the transactions still come back as “Authorized/Pending Capture” in need it to be “Captured/Pending Settlement”
…oh please help!